# Is there any reason to write this facade as a monostate

Tags: c++, facade

I am currently writing a facade for the Windows API that allows users to change the color of text in the console. The instructor states that this should be written as a monostate class to prevent multiple screen buffers from existing at once. This issue is that I'm not certain how that would happen as the sceen buffer info in set in the Write() method of the console class, and set back before exiting the method. The constructor only sets the standard handle, and that is a static variable, so by definition only one should exist anyway correct? Is there any reason that this class should be written such that the user cannot create an instance of the class?

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>


enum class Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE, WHITE};


class Console
{
    inline static HANDLE m_Std;
    static Console m_Instance;
    static WORD GetColor(Color color);
    Console();
    

public:
    static void Write(const std::string& text, Color color = Color::WHITE);
    static void WriteLine(const std::string& text, Color color = Color::WHITE);
};



#include "Console.h"
#include <stdexcept>

Console Console::m_Instance;

WORD Console::GetColor(Color color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case Color::RED:
        return FOREGROUND_RED;
    case Color::GREEN:
        return FOREGROUND_GREEN;
    case Color::BLUE:
        return FOREGROUND_BLUE;
    }

    return FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
}

Console::Console()
{
    m_Std = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
}


void Console::Write(const std::string& text, Color color)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufferInfo{};

    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(m_Std, &bufferInfo))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Error while retrieving console information" };
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(m_Std, GetColor(color));
    DWORD written{};
    WriteConsoleA(m_Std, text.c_str(), text.length(), &written, nullptr);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(m_Std, bufferInfo.wAttributes);
}

void Console::WriteLine(const std::string& text, Color color)
{
    Write(text + "\n", color);
}
```

Comment: It is possible that your instructor is using this to either teach you, or ensure you have practice, writing monostates.  It is also arguable that if you have a class whose entire state is static and global, then having multiple instances is code smell.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not sure if in Windows API you can have multiple stdouts per process, but if so, then `GetStdHandle` could return different handles for different instances. It would affect `m_Std` seen by all other instances and potentially causing bugs. `Console` class thus should be properly documented that all instances represent a console of the most recently constructed `Console`. Or yeah - monostate with the first ever Console.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov You can change what the `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` is at runtime.  So yes, there are quirks.  OTOH, possibly this class shouldn't store the `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` is, but get it when it needs it.  Myself, `Console::Write` looks like a non-member function.  A `ColoredOutput` that remembers the color and lets you write through it could be useful, but that isn't what the OP posted either.

Comment: I appreciate all of your inputs. These answers are very helpful.